# Ridge Regression - Increase of the error on the trainings set

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, regularization, ridge-regression

Given a Matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a target vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, I am searching for a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that 
    $$A\cdot x = y.$$
To  solve this problem I am using sklearn Ridge regression. Since the problem may not be exactly solvable, we introduce a regularization parameter $\alpha$ and penalize the $L_2$ norm of $x$. We are ending up with the  minimization problem
    $$\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} ||A\cdot x - y||_{L_2} + \alpha ||x||_{L_2}.$$
Now we expand the Matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ by an additional column to some matrix $\tilde{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times (n+1)}$ and searching for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. This should lead to a drop of the error or at least to the same error, but not to a larger error, since setting simply $x_{n+1}=0$ would lead to the previous case. 
Nevertheless I observe the opposite, the error increasing when expanding the matrix simply by one column in the following **example**:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

#regularization parameter
alpha = 0.1

y = np.array([-97191 ,-6, -23, 29, 76])

# the first smaller matrix
A = np.array([[  9.,  11.,  -3.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   1.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.]])

# the matrix A enlarged by one column
A_tilde = np.array([[  9.,  11.,  -3.,  -7.],
                    [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                    [  0.,   0.,   1.,   1.],
                    [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                    [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])

# ridge regression for first matrix
print('first case\n-----------')
clf = Ridge(alpha)
clf.fit(A, y)
score = clf.score(A, y)
rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, clf.predict(A)))
print('score: ' + str(score))
print('rms: ' + str(rms))

# ridge regression for enlarged matrix
print('second case\n-----------')
clf = Ridge(alpha)
clf.fit(A_tilde, y)
score = clf.score(A_tilde, y)
rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, clf.predict(A_tilde)))
print('score: ' + str(score))
print('rms: ' + str(rms))
```

Which gives me the **output**:

```
first case
-----------
score: 0.999995604615
rms: 81.5210118439
second case
-----------
score: 0.99999009637
rms: 122.368124867
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: How did you decide on alpha=0.1?

Comment: Hi Alchemist, thanks for the question. alpha=0.1 was arbitrarily chosen. If I increase the alpha, the difference in the error gets worse.

Comment: What happens when you decrease your alpha, to like .01?

Comment: when letting alpha to zero, the error is getting closer and eventually will be equal in alpha=0. This is a plot for different alphas for the root mean squared error: https://imgur.com/HwLhFWP and for the score function: https://imgur.com/44T8ZZ4.

Comment: so when the algorithm minimizes |Ax-y|+alpha|x| it tends to take the new column into account, since thus its able to reduce the L_2 norm of x. And reducing the L_2 is more profitable than reducing the actual error. But I don't fully understand what this says about my model.